# Weird behavior accessing EditText in Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I'm using a swipeable tab layout with 3 tabs using `Viewpager` and `FragmentPagerAdapter`. Each tab holds a fragment with only one EditText so far. In the main activity that `extends FragmentActivity` I'm trying to access their values on click on the action icon. The code from the main activity below works fine as long as the second tab is focused. Hower, when tab 1 or 3 is focused the activity crashes with a NullPointerException. The code of the fragment classes and their layouts are equivalent. So far I couldn't figure out why the success of this method is dependent on the tab position. I'd appreciate any clue on this.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    edt1 = (EditText) viewpager.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edt2 = (EditText) viewpager.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    edt3 = (EditText) viewpager.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_save_new_flight) {
        String msg = edt1.getText().toString() + "\n" + 
            edt2.getText().toString() + "\n" + edt3.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

#### EDIT:

I assume the issue here is that android only keeps the focused and adjacent tabs/layouts in memory. When tab 1 is active NPE occurs in editText3 (tab 3) and when tab 3 is active it occurs in editText1 (tab 1). So what's a proper way to access the texts?

Comment: Can we assume that the NPE is occurring on one of the lines you've shown in your code example? If not, please post the code where the NPE is occurring.

Comment: Sry, yes it crashes in the line creating the `String msg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, a view pager will keep instantiated only the current fragment and one on each side. When you're on fragment 1, there is no instance of fragment 3 in the pager.

You can change this with the function [setOffscreenPageLimit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) on the pager. But what you should really do is save the values in a database from the fragments and re fetch them when you click on the button (not in the ui thread of course).

It is generally a bad idea to access data of a fragment directly from the containing activity (or an other fragment). Either save the data to a database, use intents or a bus to communicate between activities/fragments.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Anyway I'd rather walk around `setOffscreenPageLimit`.